# Adding file information to an AWK comparison

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using awk to perform a file comparison against a file listing in found.txt

```
while read line; do
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}$1 in a' $line compare.txt >> $CHECKFILE  
done < found.txt
```

found.txt contains full path information to a number of files that may contain the data.  While I am able to determine that data exists in both files and output that data to $CHECKFILE, I wanted to be able to put the line from found.txt (the filename) where the line was found.

In other words I end up with something like:

`File " /xxxx/yyy/zzz/data.txt "contains the following lines in found.txt $line`

just not sure how to get the /xxxx/yyy/zzz/data.txt information into the stream.

Appended for clarification:
The file found.txt contains the full path information to several files on the system

```
/path/to/data/directory1/file.txt
/path/to/data/directory2/file2.txt
/path/to/data/directory3/file3.txt
```

each of the files has a list of parameters that need to be checked for existence before appending additional information to them later in the script.

so for example, file.txt contains the following fields

```
parameter1 = true
parameter2 = false
...
parameter35 = true
```

the compare.txt file contains a number of parameters as well.
So if parameter35 (or any other parameter) shows up in one of the three files I get it's output dropped to the Checkfile.

Both of the scripts (yours and the one I posted) will give me that output but I would also like to echo in the line that is being read at that point in the loop.  Sounds like I would just be able to somehow pipe it in, but my awk expertise is limited.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want but try this (no shell loop required):

```
awk '
ARGIND==1 { ARGV[ARGC] = $0; ARGC++; next }
ARGIND==2 { keys[$1]; next }
$1 in keys { print FILENAME, $1 }
' found.txt compare.txt > "$CHECKFILE"
```

ARGIND is gawk-specific, if you don't have it add `FNR==1{ARGIND++}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am working in a limited linux environment and cannot be sure that GAWK will be available. AWK is. In an earlier part of the script I did a search for all files of a type storing their full path information in 'found.txt'  This is what I'm passing into the comparison command.  In my sample files I have a couple of lines that are the same in both so I know the command is working.  I just want to be able to output the line currently being read in 'found.txt' along with the actual data.

Comment: I understand all of that and I believe the answer I posted solves your problem as well as enhancing it to not require a shell loop.

Comment: Ed, I tried the command you provided and got the same output.  It prints the line that was found in one of the three files in the sample set, but doesn't tell me which file the line came from.

Comment: That is not possible since it is explicitly printing the `FILENAME` variable. Please update your question to show the command you are running, the input you are running it against, and it's output.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name into `awk` inside a variable like this:

```
awk -v file="$line" '{... print "File: " file }'
```

Comment: I was able to get this command to dump the line to the screen but not append it to the file output.  Not sure why.